# CloudScribe error

Tags: c#, .net-core, cloudscribe

When I browse at 'Site Settings, I get an error and how do resolve this issue?

This happens when I create a new project using the CloudScribe framework.

Parameter name: you must pass in an implementation of ISiteSettings

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
```

Parameter name: you must pass in an implementation of ISiteSettings
   at cloudscribe.Core.Web.Components.SiteDataProtector.UnProtect(ISiteSettings site)
   at cloudscribe.Core.Web.Components.SiteManager.d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at cloudscribe.Core.Web.Controllers.Mvc.SiteAdminController.d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__12.MoveNext()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug in a recent package release that caused that error. It has since been fixed. If you right click the solution node and choose "Manage Nuget Packages for Solution", and then visit the updates tab to update to the latest version of all packages, it will fix the error.